# Stack Overflows in the Eclipse JSP Editor

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, stack-overflow

When editing JSPs in Eclipse, I periodically get stack overflows.  Once I get one, each time I click a character I get a pop-up telling me there was another stack overflow.  This continues until I close the JSP and re-open it, at which time it's fine for a while.

```
org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.internal.parser.JSPSourceParser: 
    input could not be parsed correctly at position 1
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Has anyone else seen this issue, do you know the cause, and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Maybe file a bug report?

Comment: The bug mentioned below covered it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of [JSP (WTP)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) are you using? (what version of eclipse are you using as well?)

Is the error message one like this:

```
org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core.internal.parser.JSPSourceParser: input could not be parsed correctly at position 1
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

(as reported in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg28494.html)?)

The [bug **265380**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=265380) reports a fix for [WTP 3.0.5](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.0.5/) and as such would impact an eclipse Ganymede SR2 (i.e. 3.4.2).
[WTP3.1](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.1.0/) has also this bug fixed, and is for eclipse Galileo (3.5)

Comment: I'm using 3.0.4.v20081119... so before 3.0.5.  Didn't find that when I was looking around - that is the error I'm getting and that's clearly the problem I'm having.  So 3.0.5, eh?  Not showing up in the updates yet, hopefully soon.  Thanks!

Comment: Not showing in the update? Strange, but that depends on the version of the eclipse you are using. You could test that by making a parallel eclipse installation (3.4.2 or 3.5)